# QGIS Composer keep reference after reloading layers

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer, printing, atlas

I have written a plugin which loads a bunch of geojson data via REST for a specific region, which is selected by the user, afterwards generates some vector grids over the extend and styles all the layer by default.

I have also created some pre-defined composer templates. In one of those templates an atlas is generated with an overview map (like in this example: http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html)

The problem I have is, that when the user starts with a fresh project and loads the data, in the Atlas print composer all the relations to the layers are lost (I guess because they are reloaded and so there are no reference to the print composer template anymore).

Is there a way to set this reference programmatically each time the data is loaded or can I set the refrence by the layer name or some layer tags?

The amount of layers is always the same.

EDIT:

I also have this problem with attribute data which comes via REST in a csv file and should prefill some text fields in the print composer.